# Why is it too slow to fetch the records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the gem called ['yourub'](https://github.com/edap/yourub) to fetch information of multiple videos narrowed down by particular keyword.

My code is just like this and it works fine but too slow until the result start showing up on the page.
Is it because I'm using the gem? Does it get faster if I do the same thing with native way of using "google-api-client" gem? If so how can I replace my original?

P.S. According to the document of 'yourub', it only can fetch up to 50 videos:(
and it cannot even choose which page of the result to show with pagination select :(

**My code(View)**

```
<% client = Yourub::Client.new %>

<% client.search(query: "cat", order: "date", max_results: 30) do |video| %>

Video ID:<%= video["id"] %> <br />
Title: <%= video["snippet"]["title"] %><br />
<img src="<%= video["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["high"]["url"] %>" with="480" height="360"><br />
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: Maybe, you should Ajaxify the call.  Maybe the test server is slow.  I doubt that the Gem is what causing the delay

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Thanks for a comment. So you think there won't be any big difference even if I do it natively with google-api-client?  Actually, I'm doing it on my production mode.  Okay, I'll probably implement ajax loading then. But what about selection particular page of the result page and this gem won't fetch more than 50 results???

Comment: why not use yt directly? Check http://www.sitepoint.com/youtube-api-version-3-rails/ I think it will use the google-api and it seems like the way to go

Comment: For the max results, you are stuck with 50.  You can create a custom script to pull 50 and another for the next 50 and stick them together.  Check the maxResults parameter here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Answer (score 2):

You could try YouTube's native API and see how long a search query takes to return via that one. If it is lighting fast, then it might be this gem is causing a delay.

Consider using the bullet gem (https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) and mini profiler (https://github.com/jaigouk/miniprofiler) to get more data on what's going on in your application. Look for other speed-assessing gems and see what might work.

Lastly, and this is purely a magic trick in perception, consider putting out a dumb "Fetching your results..." kind of loading indicator. Humans are wired to feel that your process is taking longer, if they don't see any change. If, however, you say "Fetching ..." , "Compiling ...", "Presenting..." , no one would even blink about the delay :)

Comment: Is there any other substitution way to compare with this way?